# Test for win in 2D array of chars with predefined array and win length - Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a checkWin method to return true if there is a winning combination. I am using nested for loops. The board size and win size are predefined in the game class and are passed to the board class when initializing the 2D array and when checking for win. I want to be able to use this check method for winning combinations of any size on a board of any size. That way I can reuse the method for multiple games. Tic Tac Toe, Connect Four, Gomoku, etc.

Why isn't it working properly? I'm pretty sure my if statements are wrong. I will get wins during some tests but not during others. And I never have wins in North West diagonal and only on one Northeast diagonal. I can easily test for certain lengths, but I am having trouble testing for any possible size board with any size of win length.

```
/**
 * Tests board initialized with size parameter in class constructor.
 * Utilizes nested loops to check all rows, columns, and diagonals for win.
 * 
 * @param WIN_SIZE, The size to check for valid win.
 * @return, Returns true if there is a winner.
 */
public boolean checkWin(int WIN_SIZE)
{
    //Test columns
    //Loop through columns
    for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) 
    {
        //Loop through rows
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) 
        {
            //Loop through win length
            for (int counter = 0; counter < WIN_SIZE; counter++)
            {
                try
                {
                if (board[counter][col] == '_' || board[counter][col] != board[counter+1][col])
                {
                    //Break if spot is blank or if next index does not match.
                    break;
                }
                if (counter == WIN_SIZE - 1)
                {
                    //Returns true when for loop has gone through WIN_SIZE-1 iterations indicating a winning combination
                    return true;
                }
                }
                catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Test rows
    //Loop through rows
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) 
    {
        //Loop through columns
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) 
        {
            //Loop through win length
            for (int counter = 0; counter < WIN_SIZE; counter++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (board[row][counter+col] == '_' || board[row][counter+col] != board[row][counter+col+1])
                    {
                        //Break if spot is blank or if next index does not match
                        break;
                    }
                    if (counter == WIN_SIZE - 1)
                    {
                        //Returns true when for loop has gone through WIN_SIZE-1 iterations indicating a winning combination
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    //Test Diagonals North-West
    //Loop through column
    for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) 
    {
        //Loop through rows
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) 
        {
            //Loop through length of a valid win
            for (int counter = 0; counter < WIN_SIZE; counter++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (board[row+counter][counter] == '_' || board[row+counter][counter] != board[row+counter+1][counter+1])
                    {
                        //Break if spot is blank or if next index does not match
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (counter == WIN_SIZE - 1)
                    {
                        //Returns true when for loop has gone through WIN_SIZE-1 iterations indicating a winning combination
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Test Diagonals North-West
    //Loop through rows
    for (int col = 0; col < size; col++)
    {
        //Loop through columns
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
        {
            //Loop through length of a valid win
            for (int counter = 0; counter < WIN_SIZE; counter++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (board[row-counter][counter] == '_' || board[row-counter][counter] != board[row-counter-1][counter+1])
                    {
                        //Break if spot is blank or if next index does not match
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (counter == WIN_SIZE - 1)
                    {
                        //Returns true when for loop has gone through WIN_SIZE-1 iterations indicating a winning combination
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Returns false if no winner is found
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am so putting the homework tag on this puppy

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following checks in your code:

```
if (board[counter][col] == '_' || board[counter][col] != board[counter+1][col])

if (board[row+counter][counter] == '_' || board[row+counter][counter] != board[row+counter+1][counter+1])

if (board[row-counter][counter] == '_' || board[row-counter][counter] != board[row-counter-1][counter+1])
```

When you index into `board`, you're using either `row` and `count`, or `col` and `count`. However, each of the checks should be using all three variables. Otherwise you're only finding combinations that start either at the left or at the top edge of the board.

It looks like you got it right in one of the loops (the one that tests rows), but not in the other three.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. I will keep goofing around with it, but thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I figured it out:

```
//Test Rows
board[row][counter+col] == '_' || board[row][counter+col] != board[row][counter+col+1]

//Test Columns
board[counter+row][counter+col] == '_' || board[counter+row][counter+col] !=     board[counter+row+1][counter+col+1]

//Test NW Diagonal
(board[counter+row][counter+col] == '_' || board[counter+row][counter+col] != board[counter+row+1][counter+col+1])

//Test NE Diagonal
board[row-counter][col+counter] == '_' || board[row-counter][col+counter] != board[row-counter-1][col+counter+1]
```